# Web-Dev with AngularJS: What kind of server software should I use?

Tags: ajax, angularjs, jsp

I have a question about the concept:

I was out of the web development practices for ~3-4 years, and now, when I try to return to it and to adopt the last technologies, I am very confused.

In the past, I was used to use JSP/PHP/Java Servlets, or some other technology that processes the page in the server and then sends it to the client. For example (JSP):

```
<% for (String s : names) { %>
    <% =s %>
    </br>
<% } %>
```

If I understand correctly, nowadays, **AngularJS** should perform the loop on the client, instead of Java on the server, and the data should be achieved by the client in JSON format, using an AJAX call to the server.

1. Is my understanding correct?
2. If so - I think that all I need is a server that will enable me to define the AJAX functions - I don't need to mix server code with client code anymore (I.e. I don't need JSP / PHP / Java Servlets / etc.). So are there new simple server technologies that are designated to enables these AJAX calls? Which server technologies are recommended and commonly used for these targets in Java and in Python nowadays?

Comment: Scriptlets are a big code smell in JSP, so that's a pretty bad example. ;) This question may also be slightly off topic for SO and may be better suited for Software Recommendations. Anyway, if you need lots of business logic on back end, Java + Spring or Play Framework are popular choices. If you just want a lightweight (little business logic) back end and cheaply serve lots of calls, MEAN (MongoDB, Express, AngularJS & Node.js) is a simple & hyped technology stack these days. There is a plethora of other options naturally, but for these at least you're guaranteed to find help aplenty online.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! By the way, it is not only regarding software recommendation - it's first about the concept, as I was not sure how it works today. You're right that it is also about recommendation, as I actually don't know any server tool that is commonly used today for these modern practices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct. AngularJS is one option, there are other JavaScript frameworks that work in a similar manner - Angular seems to be the most popular at the moment.

As for the server, you can use pretty much any technology there, the standard is to provide JSON data through RESTful web services.

Node.js with Express is popular (and easy to use), if you want to use JavaScript on the server as well.

If you want to use Java, you can use something like JBoss or Jetty as a server and then expose your services using something like [Resteasy](http://resteasy.jboss.org) as RESTful services. It's fairly easy to add to an existing application.

I recommend that you start with the [Angular tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial), which will go through many of these concepts in great detail. It's a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

As has been suggested, your back-end server will send a JSON to the client. The client can then render the HTML on the page dynamically using a front-end framework like AngularJS.

It doesn't matter what the back-end language is. However, for best performance, some people recommend that you put an additional [back-end layer between your server and the browser](http://nerds.airbnb.com/isomorphic-javascript-future-web-apps/) where you render your HTML before sending it to the browser. They say this results in better performance and search engine optimization. Node.js works well as a rendering layer, so you might as well simplify your technology stack and use use Node.js for your entire back-end.

Also, server-side rendering is easier to achieve with some front-end frameworks than others. This is one of the reasons [React](http://facebook.github.io/react/) has been trending lately. It's easier to achieve server-side rendering with it.

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood the additional layer theory you explained. Could you please tell me what is the role of the middle layer? What does it mean "between the server and the browser" - where exactly is it?

Comment: @SomethingSomething One way it could work is the browser makes a request to the server, the server sends the JSON payload to the rendering layer. The rendering layer creates the HTML, sends it back to the server, and the server responds with rendered HTML rather than a JSON payload. I don't fully understand the architecture either, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: So you actually say that the creation of the page goes back to the server's role, like in the old days of JSP, before we could embed AngularJS code and evaluate it on the client

Comment: @SomethingSomething Yes, exactly. But in the case of AngularJS, for example, you can't just throw any HTML at it and expect it to work. AngularJS itself has to generated the HTML for it to know how to continue to work with it. That's why if you wanna render AngularJS on the server you might need Node.js and PhantomJS in the back-end. I don't think React has this problem though.